# Is there an easier way to make sure a value in an array equals something php?

Tags: php

I am currently checking by doing this,

```
if($user['medicineStudy'] == 1 || $user['thievingStudy'] == 1 || $user['miningStudy'] == 1 || $user['barterStudy'] == 1 || $user['craftingStudy'] == 1 || $user['smithingStudy'] == 1)
```

But as I add values I have to manually type them in, is there not a way to search all the values and find out if they equal to 1? The array has lots of other information in it but the values I want to check always end in `Study`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$found = false;

foreach ($user as $key => $val) {
    if ($val == 1 && substr($key, -5) == 'Study') {
        $found = true;
        echo "Found a one in ".$key;
        break;
    }
}

if ($found) {
// do something
}
```

Demo: http://codepad.org/c7WehD96

Comment: @sgermain06 Sorry, I don't understand. Do you mean I was faster?

Comment: Haha! Yes, you posted the same answer as me a tiny bit faster. I removed mine, since it's a duplicate and up voted yours.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`array_filter`](http://php.net/array_filter) to probe an array for truthy entries. In your case you could combine it with [`preg_grep`](http://php.net/preg_grep) to filter out the interesting entries. Albeit you need a [`array_intersect_key`](http://php.net/array_intersect_key) workaround to apply it to the keys:

```
$true = array_filter(
   array_intersect_key($user,
   array_flip(preg_grep('/Study$/', array_keys($user))))
);
if ($true) {
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function array_search_value(&$haystack, array $keys, $needle)
{
    foreach($keys as $key)
        if($haystack[$key] == $needle) 
            return true;
    return false;
}
```